# ReactJS Can't get value from form input

Tags: reactjs, forms, api, post, http-post

I've been trying to make a form on react that sends a POST request to an external api but i can't seem to get the value on the response.
I've been following this example to get it done https://gist.github.com/whoisryosuke/578be458b5fdb4e71b75b205608f3733

and here's my code

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: ''};
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        alert('A form was submitted ' + this.state);

    fetch('http://localhost/external/api/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        return response.json();
    });

    event.preventDefault();
}

    render() {
    return (
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="chave">
                    <span>Pesquisa de produtos: </span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.value} name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" />
              </form>
        );
    }
}
```

When i click submit all i get is "A form was submitted [object Object]"

Comment: `alert('A form was submitted ' + this.state);` attempts to concatenate a string with the state object. This doesn't makes sense, so what ends up happening is the state object is coerced into a string "[Object object]". To view the actual object in the console, use a comma with `console.log` - `console.log('A form was submitted ', this.state);` or convert it to JSON `JSON.stringify(this.state)`

Answer (score 0):

write

```
event.preventDefault()
```

Earlier than fetch at the first line :)